# Iterate Through Folder and Add One Column of Each CSV to Dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a folder that contains ~90 CSV files. Each relevant file is named xxxxx-2012 and has the same column names.

I would like to create a single DataFrame with a specific column `power(MW)` from each file, *i.e.* 90 columns in total, naming the column in the resulting DataFrame by the file name.

Answer (score 1):

My objective with problems like this is to get to a simple datastructure as quickly as possible. In this case, that could be a dictionary of filenames to DataFrames.

```
frames = {filename: pd.read_csv(filename) for filename is os.listdir()}
```

*You may have to filter out bad filenames, e.g. by extension, or you may be better off using glob... in either case it breaks up the problem, this shouldn't be too bad.*

Then the question becomes much easier*:

1. How do I get one column from a DataFrame. `df[colname]`.
2. How do I concat a list of columns to a DataFrame.

**Assuming you know your way around python datastructure e.g. list comprehensions.*

---

Another option is to just concat the entire dict:

```
pd.concat(frames)
```

(which gives you a MultiIndex with all the information.)

Comment: So I figured out a different way to do it but it's definitely less elegant than yours. Using yours, I was able to get frames, but using concat isn't exactly what I want to do. For creating the dataframe from frames, would you just use a for loop to iterate through frames, and then for each item add the column on to a dataframe?

Comment: You can do pd.concat(frames, axis=1).